# Return type Object

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using data provider as part of my selenium script to validate multiple logins for an application. The code for the same is

```
@DataProvider(name="wordpressdata")
    public Object[][] passData()
    {
        Object[][] wordpress = new Object[2][2];

        wordpress[0][0] = "admin";
        wordpress[0][1] = "demo123";

        wordpress[1][0] = "admin1";
        wordpress[1][1] = "demo123";

        return wordpress;       

    }
```

In the above code, I did not get the return type mentioned is "Object". What is Object here and what is its significance. Why cannot I have some other name for Object[][] like Data[][].

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using testNG @DataProvider which must return `Object[][]`, see [here](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/DataProvider.html) for details.

And the **Object** class is the parent class of all the classes in java by default. See [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/object-class) for explanation.

Comment: It is not documented but both `Object[]` and `Iterator<Object>` are legal too since https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1161/ and TestNG 6.10

Comment: @juherr, nice, but you should document it then :)

Comment: Yes, we should. But we love contribution too and this one is easy ;p